# command is not a function

Tags: javascript, chatbot

Good afternoon all,

hopeing someone here can help, lots of web trawling and i cant work out why my app is crashing,

if i perform an command within the known commands it is fine as soon as i do a command that doesnt exist the app crashes.

no matter what i try to do with the else statement the app crashes.

any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

```
// Register our event handlers (defined below):
client.on("message", onMessageHandler);
client.on("connected", onConnectedHandler);
client.on("disconnected", onDisconnectedHandler);

// Connect to Twitch:
client.connect();

 // Called every time a message comes in:
function onMessageHandler(target, context, msg, self) {
  if (self) {
    return;
  } // Ignore messages from the bot

    // This isn't a command since it has no prefix:
  if (msg.substr(0, 1) !== commandPrefix) {
    console.log(`[${target} (${context["message-type"]})] ${context.username}: ${msg}`)
    return
  }

  // Split the message into individual words:
  const parse = msg.slice(1).split(" ");
  // The command name is the first (0th) one:
  const commandName = parse[0];
  // The rest (if any) are the parameters:
  const params = parse.splice(1);
  
  // If the command is known, let's execute it:
  if (commandName in knownCommands || knownCommandsMod) {
    // Retrieve the function by its name:
    const command = knownCommands[commandName] || knownCommandsMod[commandName]
    // Then call the command with parameters:
    command(target, context, params)
    console.log(`* Executed ${commandName} command for ${context.username}`)
  } else {
    console.log(`* Unknown command ${commandName} from ${context.username}`)
  
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you please post what debugger shows `console.log(command)`... put it just before `comand(target, ...`?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: command is not a function
No debugger available, can not send 'variables'
Process exited with code 1

thats with me putting it in the line above command(target, ...

Comment: Could you try to put `console.log(typeof command);` before `command(target, context, params)´? This should be a string...

Comment: still returning the same

Comment: Well then I think your issue is in `if (commandName in knownCommands || knownCommandsMod) {` line... could you please try `if (commandName in knownCommands || commandName in knownCommandsMod) {`? The second operator itself is returning true...

Comment: Awesome thank you that was all it was!!!! really appreciate your help